# Was the transition from establishment to voluntary church support made with "little difficulty" in the US?

Tags: church-history, civil-government, united-states

In [*A History of American Christianity*, Chapter 16](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/20160/20160-h/20160-h.htm#CHAPTER_XVI), Leonard Bacon writes:

> The transition from establishment to the voluntary system for the support of churches was made not without some difficulty, but with surprisingly little.

Is this true? I thought that the transition ran into many difficulties and oppositions?

Comment: Welcome Justin! I've taken the liberty of cleaning up your question to quote the section of Bacon's book that you appear to be talking about.  Now, one way to improve your question further would be to add more detail on why you thought the transition was very difficult.  If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: As currently presented, this question is at best opinion based, as well as being quite broad.